# Transformation of the string coefficient under T-duality

Tags: string-theory, branes, effective-field-theory, duality

I am trying to study an effective string theory valid in the low energy limit $ER<<1$. The effective action corresponds to a $D(p+1)$-brane in $R^{1,p}\times S^1$ and it is given by

$$S_{D(p+1)} = -2\pi RT_{p+1} \int d^{p+1}\sigma\left(\frac{1}{}\alpha' F_{\alpha\beta}\alpha'F^{\alpha \beta} + \frac{1}{2} (\alpha' \partial_\alpha A_z)(\alpha' \partial^\alpha A_z)+\frac{1}{2}\partial_\alpha X^i \partial^\alpha X^j \delta_{ij}\right)$$

where $F_{\alpha\beta}= \partial_\alpha A_\beta - \partial_{\beta} A_\alpha$. All the fields are massless what means that the momentum of in the compact direction (denoted by $z$) corresponds to the integer $n=0$ (it is discretised in that direction, since it is compact).

What I want to determine is how the coefficient should transform so that the action is covariant under the T-duality, but I am clueless of how to start. I know that R must transform as $\alpha'/R$ under duality but I do not know how the fields should change. My guess it is that $A_z$ should change, specially because the dimension of the D-brane will decrease by one under T-duality and this should affect $A_z$. Moreover, I am assuming that the $F_{\alpha\beta}$ should not change because they are not wrapped around the compact direction. However, I am not sure if my guess is correct or I do not understand the problem at all.

I would like some guide of how to treat the problem, specially I am interested in the transformations of the fields what it is what more problems is causing me.